# Sharepoint calendar list view webpart connected with filter

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, office365-apps

I have a requirement in office online 365 in which following things are needed.

1. Calendar list with custom field "Events", type is choice (General,Marriage,Birthday)
2. Need to create a dropdown in which above field's value should bind.
3. When user select "General" then only General events should display, birthday and marriage should not display.
4. Main thing view should be only calendar and I have tried sharepoint list filter and list view webpart but calendar view is not supported.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint OOB Features does not provide filter with calendar control. You need to implement custom code for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a self-referential calendar overlay -- create a view with a filter on the same calendar - then when creating the overlay, reference the current calendar list and the view with the filter -- give it a color and a name..  You may have to hit the resolve button to get it to find the newly created view...